# get the latest 8 records laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

How can i get the latest 8 votes on this query by mobile number field:

```
results = DB::table('votes')->whereIn('votes.id', function($query){
                    $query->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) as id'))
                    ->from('votes')
                    ->groupBy('mobile_number', 'position_id','code');
                })->where(array('code'=>$code,'position_id'=>$positionId))->get();
```

on this query it gets the latest total votes of the users but not limited to 8.

```
->where(array('code'=>$code,'position_id'=>$positionId))->take(8)->get(); //it seems this is not working
```

here's the sample table

```
id  mobile_number   code    position_id
1   123123          1       1
2   123123          3       1
3   321212          2       2
4   123123          4       1
5   123123          5       1
6   123123          6       1
7   123123          7       1
8   123123          8       1
9   123123          9       1
10  123123          10      1
```

if i get the votes of 123123 it will get only the latest 8 so on the above table the Id 1 will not be included in the results.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: If i was you i would look at eloquent it will make querying so much easier:-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

For **older** Versions

```
take(8)->skip(8)->get();
```

---

For **new** version

```
limit(8)->offset(8)->get();
```

Comment: its not getting the result

Comment: try with this `orderBy(?Query?)->take(5)->get()`

Comment: let say i have user 1 and user 2 they voted 10 times on the same position but different candidates, so the goal is to display the votes of each users but limited to latest 8 only, so meaning the old votes should not be included only the latest 8 in the display.